# Datatables server-side processing INNER JOIN or multiple tables

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Below is my code without server-side processing but as it produces many rows and will grow considerably I need to use server-side processing.

---

DB Tables (not all fields included but these are the ones i want and the fields to INNER JOIN):

```
course_modules -       id (pk), course(course.id), module(module.id), added(UNIXTIMESTAMP)
course -               id (pk), category(course_categories.id), fullname(text)
course_categories-     id (pk), name(text)
modules-               id (pk), name(text)
```

I want to be able to display the UNIXTIMESTAMP as date('d/m/Y');

---

Would this work for the INNER JOIN

```
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable 
    INNER JOIN modules ON $sTable.module = modules.id 
    INNER JOIN course ON $sTable.course = course.id 
    INNER JOIN course_categories ON course.category = course_categories.id
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
```

---

Original php version without server-side processing:

```
$mods = get_records_sql("SELECT * FROM {$CFG->prefix}course_modules");

foreach ($mods as $mod)
    {

    $thecourse = get_record('course','id',$mod->course); 
    $themodule = get_record('modules','id',$mod->module); 
    $thecat = get_record('course_categories','id',$thecourse->category); 


    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$thecat->name.'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$thecourse->fullname.'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$themodule->name.'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>';
    echo date('d/m/Y', $mod->added);
    echo'</td>'; 
    echo '</tr>'; 
    }
```

I have server-side processing woking fine with my datatables but without linking to the other tables. This table only returns IDs and I want to be able to get the value from another table as demonstrated above.

Do I need to use an innner join? If so how can I incorporate with server_processing.php script:
I used this one: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Or can I incorporate my above method within server_processing.php.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to the question: 
Problem was had 2 column names the same so i used alises in the SQL query. 
Also did not use INNER JOIN.

Columns array using the alias names and column names:

```
$aColumns = array( 'catname', 'fullname', 'modulename', 'added');
```

The SQL query for the 4 tables:

```
$sQuery = "
    SELECT mdl_course.fullname, mdl_modules.name AS modulename, mdl_course_categories.name AS catname, mdl_course_modules.added
    FROM  mdl_course_modules, mdl_modules, mdl_course, mdl_course_categories
    WHERE mdl_course_modules.module = mdl_modules.id AND mdl_course_modules.course = mdl_course.id AND mdl_course.category = mdl_course_categories.id
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes i think that you should use an inner join (but i need more details about the tables to write the exact query) and then you mustmodify the sql here

```
  $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
```

EDIT - to log the query do

```
$filename = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."logging.txt";

file_put_contents($filename, $sQuery, FILE_APPEND);
```

you should have a logging.txt file in the same directory of the script

Comment: @:Nicola Peluchetti: I have modified the question with the DB structure. Thanks

Comment: @:Nicola Peluchetti: Updates with my INNER JOIN, does this look right?

Comment: @Codded yes it should work, but in any case you should log the query (you can use firephp) and verify that  it's correct in mysql

Comment: @:Nicola Peluchetti: im getting - DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error. Is this correct? -  $aColumns = array( 'course.fullname', 'modules.name', 'course_categories.name', 'course_modules.added');

Comment: @Codded yes that could be the cause, but maybe it's just the PHP that has an error (maybe the query is not valid) and outputs a notice and so the json can't be parsed

Comment: @:Nicola Peluchetti: Sorry i dont understand, I have installed firbug but not sure how to find the answer. The table/php worked fine without the INNER JOIN

Comment: @Codded i wrote another way to log, i updated my question, after loggin the query try to execute it into mysql

Comment: @:Nicola Peluchetti: ahh i have got it now, I have got rid of the error now, the table is working fine. firebug said field did not exist. BUT it is now echoing the 4 chosen fields as blank but the pagination shows all the records have been loaded.

Comment: @Codded that's another problem, how do you set-up your datatable?

Comment: Its a prebuilt DB with moodle install. Dont think the tables are linked.