# Datatables + PHP: Server-Side Processing on Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, server-side

**How can I get Datatables *Server-Side Processing* script to work with a custom query? I need to select columns from multiple tables and have Datatables render them.**

Datatables.net's Server-Side Processing (SSP) with PHP is summarized here: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870154/datatables-server-side-processing-inner-join-or-multiple-tables), but the original poster never provided his solution. I don't have sufficient reputation to ask him to provide more detail.

Here is my raw SQL without using Datatable's SSP

```
SELECT tbl_houses.style, tbl_houses.roomCount, tbl_residents.firstName, tbl_residents.lastName
FROM tbl_houses, tbl_residents
WHERE tbl_houses.houseID = tbl_residents.residentID

/* 
* # Equivalent query using JOIN suggested by @KumarRakesh
* # Note: JOIN ... ON is a synonym for INNER JOIN ... ON
* # Using JOIN conforms to syntax spec'd by ANSI-92 https://stackoverflow.com/a/894855/946957
*
* SELECT tbl_houses.style, tbl_houses.roomCount, tbl_residents.firstName, tbl_residents.lastName 
* FROM tbl_houses 
* JOIN tbl_residents ON tbl_houses.houseID = tbl_residents.residentID
*/
```

How can I get Datatables to run queries off the above using SSP?

It appears [server_processing.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php#L22) only accepts 1 table and no custom filtering (i.e., `WHERE` clauses).

```
// DB table to use
$table = 'datatables_demo';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

However, [ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php#L199) **does** support filtering using `WHERE`. I'm thinking I need to modify `ssp.class.php` to force in my `WHERE` clause

**UPDATE**

Found a solution. Will post when I have free time.

Comment: Did you use join query in this case

Comment: You can also do it .. with SELECT tbl_house.style, tbl_house.roomCount, tbl_residents.firstName, tbl_residents.lastName
FROM tbl_house  JOIN tbl_resident ON tbl_house.houseID = tbl_resident.residentID

Comment: @KumarRakesh I'm trying to figure out how I'd cram a custom SQL query into Datatables Server-Side Processing (SSP) script.  My question is not how to construct an SQL query, but how to incorporate it into Datatables' SSP "framework" on the server side.

Comment: I think I will have to hard-wire in my custom filter (i.e., WHERE clause) into the `sss.class.php` file. Will attempt then post an update if it works

Comment: I developed a class for server side datatables that relies on PDO adapter, I have used in almost all my projects since 6 years flawlessly, I just hosted this in Github after seeeing your question, here is the link if it helps you https://github.com/oromedialab/datatables feel free to ask questions and ill do my best to respond, it supports any joins, groupby etc.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar thanks for taking the time to post your customization!  However, I fear it relies on a Datatables version prior to 1.10+.  There were substantial changes to the API from 1.x to 1.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** I ended up using a modification of the original Datatables `ssp.class.php` called [`ssp.php`](https://github.com/emran/ssp/blob/master/ssp.php) implemented by Emran Ul Hadi: https://github.com/emran/ssp

His modification accepts JOIN, WHERE, GROUP BY and column aliases. Although the file hasn't been updated in over a year, it still works with DataTables 1.12.x.  I made some modifications to his version that increases its robustness and improves the documentation with clearer examples.

Will post my mods/updates here when I have a bit more time.  Eventually I hope to put in a pull-request to get my updates into his repository.

Comment: Have you tried to modify it for supporting "UNION ALL"?

Comment: @Milson been meaning to post  a draft up to Github with a pull-request to Emran.  My mods were mainly simplification of syntax used to call ssp functions/procedures and documentation clarity. Adding `UNION` functionality should be trivial. Taking a look at the changes Emran made to turn on `JOIN` gives context on how to implement other SQL functions

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the scripts from DataTables are indeed not designed for your particular use case. But there is a method that allows for custom where clauses and from reading the source of [ssp.class.php#complex](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php#L304) I think that this configuration should work for your by using the `WHERE` method. The `JOIN` method will not work here.

Long story short: edit your server_processing.php to that:

```
<?php
// DB table to use
$table = 'tbl_houses, tbl_residents';
 
// First table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'tbl_houses.id';
 
$columns = [
    [ 'db' => 'tbl_houses.style'],
    [ 'db' => 'bl_houses.roomCount'],
    [ 'db' => 'tbl_residents.firstName'],
    [ 'db' => 'tbl_residents.lastName']
    
);

// connection details
$sql_details = [
    
];

$whereAll = 'tbl_houses.houseID = tbl_residents.residentID';

require 'ssp.class.php';

echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns , null, $whereAll);
);
```

The `complex` method accepts your custom `WHERE` clause. But the tricky thing is the usage of 2 tables. This is what the script does not seem to be designed for. I took a look on how it is building the final sql query and it appears that you may just use this `table_name.field_name` notation in the config, as well as the `table_name, table_name` notation for the `$table` and `$primaryKey` variables.

As mentioned, the usage of 2 tables is not intended by the DataTables script. I don't know if all features of DataTables will work with that.

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive!  I implemented your suggestion and you are correct!  The datatables `ssp.class.php` **does not** support multiple tables out-of-the-box. That is, `$table = 'tbl_houses, tbl_residents'` produces a _Base table or view not found: 1146_ error. However, I did find a solution and will post when I have a free minute.

Answer (score 0):

My fork of the original Datatables ssp.class.php: https://github.com/emayskiy/Datatables-SSP-MultiTables

You can alias tables and columns, use where, use [LEFT, INNER, RIGHT, CROSS] JOIN with tables. 
Example server_processing.php:

```
<?php 
    //For one table:
    //$table = "main_table_name";
    //Or for multitable queries: 
    $table = array(
        array('table'=>'main_table_name',  'as'=>'mt'),    
        array('table'=>'join1_table_name', 'as'=>'jt1', 'join_type'=>'INNER', 'join_on'=>'mt.field  = jt1.field'),
        array('table'=>'join2_table_name', 'as'=>'jt2', 'join_type'=>'LEFT',  'join_on'=>'mt.field1 = jt2.field')
    ); 
    //Columns definition with alias
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => 'mt.field1',  'dt' => 0 ),
        array( 'db' => 'mt.field2',  'dt' => 1 ),    
        array( 'db' => 'mt.name',    'as'=>'field3', 'dt' => 2 ),    
        array( 'db' => 'jt1.field1', 'as'=>'field4', 'dt' => 3 ),
        array( 'db' => 'jt2.field5', 'as'=>'field5', 'dt' => 4 )       
    );
    $primaryKey = 'mt.id'; //Primary key, for check records count
    $sql_details = array(
        'user' => $db_user,
        'pass' => $db_password,
        'db'   => $db_name,
        'host' => $db_host
    );
    $where = "mt.field1 > 10"; //You SQL where condition

    require('ssp.class.php' ); //File from github.com/emayskiy/Datatables-SSP-MultiTables
    echo json_encode(
        // All params same as in original class SSP
        SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns , '', $where)
    );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be late, but I was able to solve the problem by building my own server side file, that way I can customize both queries and json outputs.

File serverSide custom:

```
 public function produtosEstoque($arr)
    {
              
        //COLUNAS
        $column = array('prodNome', 'prodPreco', 'prodQtdEst', 'categDescricao');


        //SQL
        $query2 = "SELECT a.prodID, a.prodNome, a.prodMedida, a.prodPrecoAnt, a.prodPreco, a.prodCategoriaID, a.prodOferta,a.prodQtdEst, a.prodQtdMEst, b.categDescricao FROM produtos a INNER JOIN categoria b ON a.prodCategoriaID = b.categID WHERE a.prodEstatusID = 6 ";

        //SEARCH
        if ($arr['search']['value']) {
            $query2 .= "AND prodNome LIKE '%".$arr['search']['value']."%' ";
        }

        //ORDER
        if (isset($arr['order'])) {
            $query2 .= 'ORDER BY ' . $column[$arr['order']['0']['column']] . ' ' . $arr['order']['0']['dir'] . ' ';
        } else {
            $query2 .= 'ORDER BY a.prodID DESC ';
        }

        
        //LIMIT
        if ($arr["length"] != -1) {
            $query3 = 'LIMIT ' . $arr['start'] . ', ' . $arr['length'];
        }
        
        
        try {
            
            //TOTAL DE REGISTROS NA TABELA
            $query1 = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE prodEstatusID = 6";
            $stm1 = $this->pdo->prepare($query1);
            $stm1->execute();
            $contReg = $stm1->rowCount($stm1);   
            
            
            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($query2);
            $stm->execute();
            $number_filter_row = $stm->rowCount($stm);


            $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($query2 . $query3);
            $stm->execute();
            $list = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


            $data = [];
            foreach ($list as $row) {                                  
                $data[] = array('prod_nome' => $row->prodNome . ", " . $row->prodMedida, 'prod_preco' => "R$ ".$this->convInReal($row->prodPreco)." ".$this->formatProdOff($row->prodOferta), 'prod_estoque' => $row->prodQtdEst . " - M: " . $row->prodQtdMEst, 'prod_categoria' => $row->categDescricao);                                
            }

            $dat = array('draw' => intval($arr["draw"]), 
                  'recordsTotal' => $contReg, 
                  'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row, 
                  'data' => $data
                  );
            
            return json_encode($dat, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

        } catch (PDOException $erro) {
            $data = array('msgEr' => 'ERR_002_EI', 'erroLine' => $erro->getLine());
            return json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating view table in mysql phpmyadmin.

Run your sql script in phpmyadmin then click on **create view**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMBP7.png)